# Use variable outside the function

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, event-handling, onchange

To double-check, I try a console log both inside and outside the function.

The one inside the function is fine, but the one outside the function displays "undefined."

I need to get the value of startDate and use it outside the function.

I tried every suggestion here, but none of them worked. https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/javascript-select-onchange-get-value

here is the code:

```
var startDate;
        
$('#dayFrom, #timeFrom').change(function() {
   startDate = $('#dayFrom').val() + ' ' + $('#timeFrom').val();
   console.log("inside start date: " + startDate);
});

console.log("outside start date: " + startDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the arrow function?
You can change code to this:

```
var startDate;
    
$('#dayFrom, #timeFrom').change(() => {
startDate = $('#dayFrom').val() + ' ' + $('#timeFrom').val();
console.log("inside start date: " + startDate);
});

console.log("outside start date: " + startDate);
```

when you use the function keyword to create a function you enter in very complex area and you can avoid that area by simply using the arrow function like this.

Comment: its not working, outside start date still display "undefined"

Answer (score 0):

The `startDate` variable has already changed when the event listener runs. It is undefined because you are printing the value of it before the change event listener runs.

Comment: what should i do? i need to use the startdate variable value for other purposes

Comment: What are you trying to do with it? It has already changed when the event listener runs, and you can just use the `startDate`

Comment: I need to use the startDate for my ajax, I need to give the value for the data

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).